# Java Refreshing Auth token after 30 min

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I want to know how to keep refreshing token every 30 min. Currently i dont have it. I need to cache that token for 30 min and then replace current token with the new refresh token.

Right now when i pass 1000 records all records uses same Auth token but the program runs more than 1 hour. I get Auth token expired error for some of the records.

Can anyone help me with how to handle that scenario ?

Thanks in advance

This is call class and will be calling token class.

```
    package main.java.com.test;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
    import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;

    public class Call {
    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        new Call().execute();
    }

    public String execute() throws IOException {
        String number = "01";
        String id = "0123456789";
        String cd = "107BC0000X";

        Token getToken = new Token();

        String token = null;


        try {
            token = getToken.Token();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("access token" + token);

        return token;
    }
    }
```

This is another class called Token

```
package main.java.com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;



   public class Token {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public String Token() throws Exception
    {
        Token http = new Token();

        http.sendGet();

        String token = http.sendPost();

        return token;
    }

    private String sendPost() throws  Exception
    {

        String url = "https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/oauth/token";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpClient httpClient1 = wrapClient(client);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        post.setHeader("User-Agent" , "Mozilla/5.0");

        List urlParam =  (List) new ArrayList();
        urlParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", ""));
        urlParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", ""));
        urlParam.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", ""));

       post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParam));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient1.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            result.append(line);
        }

        String[] JsonTags0 = result.toString().split(",");
        String[] JsonTags1 = result.toString().split(":");
        String token1 = JsonTags1[1].trim();

        return token1.substring(1,37);

    }

    private void sendGet()
    {

    }

    public static HttpClient wrapClient(HttpClient base)
    {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager1();


            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] {tm},null);
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = base.getConnectionManager(ctx , SSLSocketFactory , ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
            sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf , 443));
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, base.getParams());

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to refresh the token when you get the 4XX in the response

Comment: Why not refresh the token after every execution?

Comment: I can do that but thats not right the right approach if i have large batches

Comment: @dk3 why is it not the "right" approach? I think it's the perfect approach, because it's stateless, not sensitive to changing execution duration and (most importantly) simple.

Comment: What is the token where you are getting from have limited transactions per seconds. for example if i'm running batch of 10000 and maybe the transactions for auth token are limited to 200 per sec and there are more trans going in. That would still get layer 7 issues.
I'm not saying you are incorrect. You are absolutely right. But i'm thinking about all the other scenario's.